# dynamic className with Tailwind in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am making simple 'todo' project to improve my react skill one of it feature choosing the color of task card, but I can't figure out why my approach doesn't work. Here the `code`:

```
import React from "react";

const TaskCard: React.FC = () => {
  let color = "sky";
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="bg-white h-[80px] w-[100%] flex flex-row rounded-md">
        <div className={`p-1 bg-${color}-400`}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TaskCard;
```

this is just a sample of the code my problem is `${}` doesn't work, it work when I hard code it.

Comment: Use something like tailwind-merge or clxs if you want to conditionally apply styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the following type of example code to good effect, you'll need to concatenate classes using [`clsx`](https://github.com/lukeed/clsx), I've been able to access some of the templates that come with Tailwind UI and they tend to do similar.

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';

const variants: { [key: string]: string } = {
  sky: 'bg-sky-400',
  grass: 'bg-grass-400',
  fire: 'bg-fire-400',
};

const TaskCard: React.FC<{ variant: string }> = ({ variant }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="bg-white h-[80px] w-[100%] flex flex-row rounded-md">
        <div className={clsx('p-1', variants[variant])}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TaskCard;
```

You can build out your component variants with more classes too, if you want to see something a bit more in-depth, I wrote an article on this subject: https://morganfeeney.com/how-to/create-tailwind-component-variants-using-react

Answer (score 2):

Using dynamic classes with Tailwind is not recommended because Tailwind uses tree-shaking. It means that any class that wasn't declared in your source files, won't be generated in the output file.

It would be best to use full class names when using Tailwind. From the docs about [dynamic classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is
> that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings
> in your source files.

As a last resort, Tailwind offers something called [Safelisting classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes). You can use safelist to include specific classes in your tailwind output file.

In your example, you can use [regular expressions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions) to include all the colors you want using `pattern`. You can force Tailwind to create `variants` as well:

```css
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /bg-(red|green|blue)-(400)/,
      variants: ['lg', 'hover', 'focus', 'lg:hover'],
    },
  ],
}
```