# tailwind classes not working when i transfer through props while working perfecly when i use cdn link of tailwind css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

```js
//Button.jsx

import React from 'react';

const Button = (props) => {
  let color = props.color || 'blue';

  return (
    <button className={`px-4 py-2 font-bold text-black bg-${color}-500 rounded-full hover:bg-${color}-700 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline`}>
      Click
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;


// App.jsx
import Button from "./Button"
import './index.css'
function App() {


  return (
    <div>
       <Button >Click me!</Button>
      <Button color="red">Click me!</Button>
      <Button color="green">Click me!</Button>
    </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

[this is a component where i'm transferring background color using props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpXW6.png)

i don't know what's wrong... same code just when i add cdn link of tailwindcss in html page it work but don't work without cdn.
if i will transfer bg-red-500 whole class as props then it works but if i send only red as props then it doesn't work.
even in inspect page i can see classes but they're not taking effect.
i'm using vite-react.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamic className with Tailwind in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74866025/dynamic-classname-with-tailwind-in-react)

Comment: Can you please provide your project's structure ? Where is App.jsx positioned ? And where is your tailwind.config at ?

Comment: I want you to try the above code in your react project without tailwind cdn link and ik it won't work

Answer (score 1):

I think your forgetting a step, did you do `@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;` in your main css?
The getting started also shows one more extra step: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Comment: I did complete setup and added everything :/ still not working

Comment: You also imported the CSS file?

Comment: yes and i think tailwind doesn't support dynamic classes because of purgecss it delete the unused classes..

Answer (score 0):

You must specify full class name for TailwindCss in your code:

```
const Button = (props) => {
  let color = props.color || 'blue';

  // Specify complete unbroken class names for TailwindCss:
  let bgColorClass = 'bg-blue-500';
  if(color === 'red'){
    bgColorClass = 'bg-red-500';
  }

  return (
    <button className={`px-4 py-2 font-bold text-black ${bgColorClass} rounded-full hover:bg-${color}-700 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline`}>
      Click
    </button>
  );
};
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names